# MS Word Mac How to Continue Bullet List Numbering

Tags: mac, microsoft-word

I am using MS Word for Mac v 16.16.2.  I hae a bulleted list I would like to have continue numbering on the following line.  When I press return for a new line I do not get a new bullet point.  How do you get it to continue numbering?

Answer (score 0):

If you press a single return, the numbering should continue.  If you press a second return, it goes back to normal text.  Reselecting numbering should pick up where it left off.

If you are using several returns to achieve desired spacing, you can control that with "space before" and "space after" in the paragraph formatting settings.